# 'TRIM' or 'PROPER' in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, trim

is there a way to normalize strings in BigQuery?

My dataset looks like:

> **Alfa Beta**
>
> **Alfa  BETA**
>
> **alfa beta**    *//with a space after 'beta'*

By now I can use **lower** or **upper** to normalize the letters but I don't know how to eliminate spaces before and after the text. Does BigQuery have a function like '*TRIM*' in Excel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BigQuery does have `LTRIM` (trims spaces from left) and `RTRIM` (trims spaces from right) functions. (Strings functions documentation at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#stringfunctions missed them, we will fix this shortly).

Comment: Does that mean that I have to use both like this `RTRIM(LTRIM(column_here))` to get rid of white space on both sides?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. BigQuery has support for `TRIM` to remove both leading and trailing spaces.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#trim

You can also use `LTRIM` for spaces on the left and `RTRIM` for spaces on the right.